# Java generics for method parameter with any class object

Tags: java, generics

I have a Java method which has to accept generic object.

```
Public void myMethod(Object<T> anyClassObject) {
    //handle code
}
```

The method should accept object of any class and I have to manage the content of the object.
I am not an expert in Generics.
So please help me to achieve this using Generics.

my need is to create a method which any class's instance. And then I have to save the object in database.

For saving into database, have to specify the persistent entity class as usual.

For example,

```
mongoTemplate.createCollection(One.class)
```

For an other entity,

```
mongoTemplate.createCollection(Two.class)
```

like the above.

I have to write a method which can be accessed in common

Comment: Do you need to use generics here? (Sometimes you don't, and `Object` is good enough)

Answer (score 5):

To accept a reference to any object, you don't even need generics. Simply use `Object` as the type:

```
public void myMethod(Object someObject) {
    // code ...
}
```

Generics become necessary only when you want to have multiple things with related types. For example, here's a method that takes a reference of any type, and returns the same reference with the same type:

```
public <T> T doNothing(T someObject) {
    return someObject;
}
```

`doNothing("").length()` will compile - if `doNothing` is passed a `String`, then it returns a `String`.